# React Native Maps not working with React Native Firebase with use_framework

Tags: react-native, react-native-firebase, react-native-maps

I know its a common question as React Native maps does not support `use_frameworks!` but all the solutions in the web not working for me (may be those are too complicated). May anyone please help me how to make React Native maps work with `use_frameworks! :linkage => :static` as React native Firebase demands it. I am ready for my all available bounty :(

React native version: `0.70.6`
React Native Maps: `1.3.2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to add google maps and firebase both so needed to avoid use_framwork. This is what has worked from me after two days got wasted on it.

solution is to use firebase pods like this.

```
  pod 'Firebase', :modular_headers => true
  pod 'FirebaseCore', :modular_headers => true
  pod 'FirebaseCoreInternal', :modular_headers => true  
  pod 'FirebaseStorageInternal', :modular_headers => true
  pod 'FirebaseCoreExtension', :modular_headers => true
  pod 'FirebaseAppCheckInterop', :modular_headers => true
  pod 'FirebaseAuthInterop', :modular_headers => true
  pod 'FirebaseMessagingInterop', :modular_headers => true
  pod 'GTMSessionFetcher', :modular_headers => true
  pod 'FirebaseAppCheckInterop', :modular_headers => true
  pod 'FirebaseAuthInterop', :modular_headers => true
  pod 'GoogleUtilities', :modular_headers => true
```

as explained on this link. give that person a thumbs up as well.

https://dev.to/matthewzruiz/firebase-the-following-swift-pods-cannot-yet-be-integrated-as-static-libraries-b59

my pod file:

```
require_relative '../node_modules/react-native/scripts/react_native_pods'
require_relative '../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/native_modules'

platform :ios, '13.0'
install! 'cocoapods', :deterministic_uuids => false

target 'ReactNativeBoilerPlate' do

  rn_maps_path = '../node_modules/react-native-maps'
  pod 'react-native-google-maps', :path => rn_maps_path

  config = use_native_modules!
# React Native Maps dependencies
  # Flags change depending on the env values.
  flags = get_default_flags()

  use_react_native!(
    :path => config[:reactNativePath],
    # to enable hermes on iOS, change `false` to `true` and then install pods
    :hermes_enabled => flags[:hermes_enabled],
    :fabric_enabled => flags[:fabric_enabled],
    # An absolute path to your application root.
    :app_path => "#{Pod::Config.instance.installation_root}/.."
  )

  pod 'FirebaseCore', :modular_headers => true
  pod 'GoogleUtilities', :modular_headers => true

  pod 'react-native-splash-screen', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-splash-screen'

  pod 'RNVectorIcons', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons'

  pod 'RNPermissions', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-permissions'

  target 'ReactNativeBoilerPlateTests' do
    inherit! :complete
    # Pods for testing
  end

  # Enables Flipper.
  #
  # Note that if you have use_frameworks! enabled, Flipper will not work and
  # you should disable the next line.
  # use_flipper!()

  post_install do |installer|
    react_native_post_install(installer)
    __apply_Xcode_12_5_M1_post_install_workaround(installer)
    installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
      target.build_configurations.each do |config|
        config.build_settings['EXCLUDED_ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*]'] = "arm64"
      end
    end
  end
 
end
```